# Как настроить замену с помощью регулярки

Tags: регулярные-выражения, notepad++

Нужна замена в `notepad++`:
Найти все выражения находящиеся в скобках [], но только те скобки искать в которых есть одно и тоже слово в выражении, например "ЖАБА".
Заменить на пусто.
Спасибо

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Думаю, где то такое регулярное выражение нужно

```
\[[^\[\]]*WORD[^\[\]]*\]
```

разбор по кусочкам

```
\[ - в начале должна быть скобка. Ее  нужно заекранировать, так ка это спецсимвол
[^\[\]]* - это нужно читать так. любой символ кроме (`^`) квадратных скобок 0 или более
WORD - собственно слово
[^\[\]]* - ещё раз
\] -  скобка в конце
```

А в поле "заменить на" нужно просто оставить пустоту.

Comment: УРАААААААА! Спасибо огромное. Рутина преодолена :)

Answer (score 0):

```
before[r3242dexamplefswe]after -> \[.+example.+\] = beforeafter
```

Вводите свое повторяющие слово, а вот само чтоб искало совпадение и потом стирала, одной регулярным выражением хм ...

Comment: я может не до конца комментировал. Если находит скобку с таким словом, то удалить нужно и скобки и всё выражение, которое находится в этой скобке!